# Remove duplicate column pairs, sort rows based on 2 columns

Tags: r

in the following dataframe I want to keep rows only once if they have duplicate pairs (1 4 and 4 1 are considered the same pair) of `Var1` and `Var2`. I thought of sorting `Var1` and `Var2` within the row and then remove duplicate rows based on both `Var1` and `Var2`. However, I don't get to my desired result.

This is what my data looks like:

```
Var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,5)
Var2 <- c(4,3,2,1,5,5)
f <- c("blue","green","yellow","red","orange2","grey")
g <- c("blue","green","yellow","red","orange1","grey")
testdata <- data.frame(Var1,Var2,f,g)
```

I can sort within the rows, however the values of columns f and g should remain untouched, how do I do this?

```
testdata <- t(apply(testdata, 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))
testdata <- as.data.table(testdata)
```

Then, I want to remove duplicate rows based on `Var1` and `Var2`

I want to get this as a result:

```
Var1 Var2 f       g
1    4    blue    blue
2    3    green   green
5    5    orange2 orange1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of sorting for the whole dataset, sort the 'Var1', 'Var2', and then use `duplicated` to remove the duplicate rows

```
testdata[1:2] <- t( apply(testdata[1:2], 1, sort) )
testdata[!duplicated(testdata[1:2]),]
#   Var1 Var2       f       g
#1    1    4    blue    blue
#2    2    3   green   green
#5    5    5 orange2 orange1
```

Answer (score 10):

In case people are interested in solving this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
testdata %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(key = paste(sort(c(Var1, Var2)), collapse="")) %>%
   distinct(key, .keep_all=T) %>%
   select(-key)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#    Var1  Var2       f       g
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <fctr>  <fctr>
# 1     1     4    blue    blue
# 2     2     3   green   green
# 3     5     5 orange2 orange1
```

Comment: How does this work? This is really cool. I thought paste works by pasting the two columns in that order, yet my column pairs have a key that is the same for each duplicate pair.

Answer (score 4):

If the data are large, as in [Sort large amout of data and save repeated pairs of values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420089/sort-large-amout-of-data-and-save-repeated-pairs-of-values-in-r), using `apply()` on each row will be expensive. Instead, create the set of unique values

```
uid = unique(unlist(testdata[c("Var1", "Var2")], use.names=FALSE))
```

determine whether a swap is necessary

```
swap = match(testdata[["Var1"]], uid) > match(testdata[["Var2"]], uid)
```

and update

```
tmp = testdata[swap, "Var1"]
testdata[swap, "Var1"] = testdata[swap, "Var2"]
testdata[swap, "Var2"] = tmp
```

remove duplicates as before

```
testdata[!duplicated(testdata[1:2]),]
```

If there were many additional columns, and copying these were expensive, a more self-contained solution would be

```
uid = unique(unlist(testdata[c("Var1", "Var2")], use.names=FALSE))
swap = match(testdata[["Var1"]], uid) > match(testdata[["Var2"]], uid)
idx = !duplicated(data.frame(
    V1 = ifelse(swap, testdata[["Var2"]], testdata[["Var1"]]),
    V2 = ifelse(swap, testdata[["Var1"]], testdata[["Var2"]])))
testdata[idx, , drop=FALSE]
```